# How to turn off url aliases on dev site?

Tags: path-aliases, uri

I'm using path auto to automatically generate url aliases. On my dev site it would be convenient to use standard node/123 urls. 
Is there a way to do that? Just turning off pathauto and path won't do the trick

Comment: unless I am once again missing the point, node/# will work regardless of whether an alias is set

Comment: yes, it will work but I would like to have node/# be used for links on the dev site so I can quickly mouse over the links and see the node ids

Comment: if you are creating them with `l()` you should be able to set the alias option to TRUE, and then the alias won't be looked up and will leave the node/# in place...

Comment: of course, d'oh! this sets up a different code base for your development system unless you have a admin setting / variable you can access to toggle this

Comment: or just set the aliases to include the nid, eg, node/123 aliases to foo/123 and then your mouse overs will give you the nid you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the `{url_alias}` still has the aliases in it.

My suggestion would be to take a backup, then delete a few manually from "admin/build/path" (Drupal 6) or "admin/config/search/path" (Drupal 7), and then try the "node/nid" paths for the entries you deleted.  Then, take another backup :) and either delete them via the **Delete aliases** tab.